# Error While Printing Report

Tags: report, odoo, wkhtmltopdf, odoo-9

I am getting following error while printing report.

> Wkhtmltopdf failed (error code: -11). Message:

I don't know how to fix it. please help me.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Can you share more details? What is the error message other than what you have shared?

Comment: @HardikPatadia, there is not more information is printing in log. i have already install wkhtmltopdf, and my other reports are working fine.

i am getting this error while print report that have large amount of data.

Comment: Check this link https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/wkhtmltopdf-failed-error-code-11-75795#answer_98751

Answer (score 0):

sudo aptitude install ia32-libs